# Python: rounding error distorts uniform distribution

Tags: python, random, rounding, rounding-error

I need to sample 10 uniformly distributed random numbers between 0 and 1. So I thought the following code in python would do this:

```
positions = []
for dummy_i in range(1000000):
    positions.append(round(random.random(),1))
```

However when putting the result into a histogram the result looks as follows:

[image: Frequency of numbers rounded to 1 decimal place]

So the rounding seems to destroy the uniform distribution generated by random.random(). I wonder what causes this and how to prevent this from happening. Thanks for your help!

Comment: An easy way to get the counts (and to see that it's the histogram binning that's distorting things) is to use `collections.Counter`: try `collections.Counter(round(random.random(), 1) for _ in range(10**6))` and you'll see that the counts are roughly equal for `0.1` through to `0.9`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have a problem later in the code... (e.g. when collecting the statistics). Check this smaller snippet:

```
import random, collections
data = collections.defaultdict(int)
for x in range(1000000):
    data[round(random.random(),1)] += 1
print(data)
```

You will see that `0` and `1` of course have about half of the samples of the other values that are all pretty much uniform.

For example I got:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>,
            {0.4: 100083,
             0.9: 99857,
             0.3: 99892,
             0.8: 99586,
             0.5: 100108,
             1.0: 49874,     # Correctly about half the others
             0.7: 100236,
             0.2: 99847,
             0.1: 100251,
             0.6: 100058,
             0.0: 50208})    # Correctly about half the others
```

Answer (score 2):

Your way of creating the histogram is wrong. You should get roughly:

50k for 0 and 1

100k for all other numbers

But your third bin is from 0.2 inclusive to 0.3 inclusive, resulting in 200k while your fourth bin is from 0.3 exclusive to 0.4 exclusive resulting in zero.

Try to create a histogram where the edges are 0.05, 0.15 etc, then you won't have such precision errors.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
positions = []
for dummy_i in range(10):
    positions.append(random.randint (0, 10) / 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be cleaner and more efficient to use Numpy here:

```
import numpy as np
positions = np.random.random(10000)
positions = np.round(positions, decimals=3)
```

Comment: Hmm. This isn't really an answer to the OP's question: it's a comment, masquerading as an answer.